# Django Composite Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to create a composite foreign in Django and use the key to create and update certain entries?

I have looked at the package django-composite-foreignkey. However, it doesn't provide a way to use the key for creating/updating

As an example:

I have

```
class tree(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tree_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tree_age = models.IntegerField()

class branch(models.Model):
    tree_id = models.ForeignKey('tree',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch_id = models.IntegerField()
    branch_length = models.FloatField()
    Branch_width = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together(('tree_id','branch_id'),)

class leaf(models.Model):
    tree_id = models.ForeignKey('tree',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch_id = models.ForeignKey('branch',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leaf_id = models.IntegerField()
    leaf_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    leaf_length = models.FloatField()
    leaf_width = models.FloatField()
    worm_bites = models.IntegerField()


    class Meta:
        unique_together(('tree_id','branch_id','leaf_id')
```

And I want to create a new leaf say

```
#not working
leaf.objects.create(tree_id = 2, branch_id = 2, leaf_id = 1, leaf_color = 'brown'.....)
```

This doesn't work, as it will give me a ForeignKey error. I guess is because the *branch_id* is not a primary key in BRANCH.

So I am wondering if there is a way to use composite Primary Key / composite Foreign Key in Django?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Stargazer, what I'm trying to achieve here is that I have 3 layers of tables, say TREE, BRANCH, LEAVES. BRANCH has a foreign key to TREE. But for LEAVES, I need to have a composite foreign key to get the TREE and the BRANCH.

Comment: @QiaoJian, that would be redundant. If leaves are connected to a branch and the branch is connected to a tree, then you have an implicit connection from every leaf to a tree.

Comment: `use the key to create and update certain entries` what does this mean? Please clarify the scenario you're talking about.

Comment: @EndreBoth I have just updated my question. Can you please see if you can help me?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Hi Ivan, I have just updated my question. Can you please see if you can help me with this question?

Comment: Please share full error message. And check whether you have tree with id=2 and branch with id=2.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object that has a foreign key, you have to pass an object (not just an `id`) that has been saved to the database previously. For instance:

```
branch = Branch.objects.get(id=1)
tree = branch.tree
Leaf.objects.create(tree=tree, branch=branch ...)
```

A few tipps on naming conventions: Classes should be camel cased: Branch, BigBranch and Leaf. Models should be singular. Foreign keys should be named after the model if possible, but without a trailing `_id`. The Django code actually is an excellent example of Python naming conventions.

As to the composite key business, you don't need composite foreign keys if you design your database accordingly. In this particular case, every item in the hierarchy should only point to the next-higher level. Imagine if you had a `Forest`. What would you do, add a third foreign key to `Leaf`? No need: `Leaf` points to `Branch`, `Branch` to `Tree`, and `Tree` to `Forest`, and you can always go through that chain to find which forest a leaf is in without saving a reference to the forest in `Leaf`.

The Django documentation (which is excellent in many ways) has very useful [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/) on how to define relationships.